# Looking for popup cheat sheet for windows

Tags: windows, information-management, keyboard-shortcuts, documentation-viewer

I am a web developer - and I also work with the windows command line; bash command line; and several advanced digital audio workstations, as wells as graphic design software.  I'm only saying this to make the point that I need to remember lots of commands and facts - and as I'm often using different programming languages/libraries, lots of different programming arguments, functions, etc.  Keyboard shortcuts also... In short - a lot of stuff.

What I'm looking for is some kind of popup sidebar that stores various commands and data.  I've tried my hand at making something like this several times, but it always begins to look like it is going to take too long and not really do what I want the way I want.  Ideally this would have a simple way to feed data into, and perhaps could parse display multiple different filetypes; e.g. `.man,.chm,.md,.txt,.rdoc`,.etc.  Also it would have to be lightweight (like Ideally no window frame at all - this seems doable on windows 10), low on resources, quickly togglable with an easy shortcut.

This is a concept image:

[image: Concept]
<sup>Concept (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Actually - it'd be kind of like the Windows 10 notification center, but it would display useful stuff instead of multiple options I don't need.

One more thing.  I know this is theoretically possible with Rainmeter, but for various reasons I'd like a different solution.

Comment: Why does Rainmeter not work for you? Could you expand on what features it lacks or has that you don't want?

Comment: @Tom It uses a lot of memory and becomes clunky.  In addition, with the modules I've seen, there is no way to achieve the kind of flexible formatting I desire.  Also, I don't recall keyboard shortcuts being an option, but I could be wrong.